# How can I keep hidden columns hidden after grouping columns?

Tags: excel, vba

I have several columns grouped together in excel and within these grouped columns I have some of the columns hidden. However, when I expand the grouped columns Excel automatically un-hides the hidden columns. How do I keep these columns hidden?

Deleting the contents of these columns isn't an option as I'm using a pivot table and I need the calculations. I am open to using vba.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply multiple levels of Grouping.

First, Group the columns you want to hide.  This will give you levels 1 (columns hidden) and 2 (all columns visible)

Then, group the wider range of columns you were grouping before.  This will give you 3 levels: 1 (all groups closed) 2 (second groups visible, first groups hidden) and 3 (all groups open)

So, you can then toggle between levels 1 and 2 to keep the hidden columns hidden